# Having Timestamp in Entity Framework actually tell the code the date of change

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I need my entities in EF 4.3 code first environment to know when they were updated last time. Is it possible? If yes, then how to get the time of the last altering in the entity class having the following property:

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

I need to get the time of update from the method in this very same entity class.

Comment: You **cannot** do something like that. The SQL Server `TIMESTAMP` (or `ROWVERSION`) datatype **has nothing to do** with date or time - it's just a sequential number used to detect changes to rows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `DateTime` property called `UpdatedOn` (or whatever) to your model.

```
public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
```

Then in your code, I assume you have an `Update()` (or something similar) you can set it

```
UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now
```

That way, everytime the Update method is called on a row, the UpdatedOn property will be set to the exact time the method was executed.